# Second order Fibonacci numbers

Tags: discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

Let's consider a recurrence: 
$A_{0}=0$, $A_{1}=1$, $
A_{n}=A_{n-1}+A_{n-2}+F_{n}$, where $F_{n}$ is the $n$th Fibonacci number. How to express $A_{n}$ in a closed form?

Despite the fact that it sounds easy, i got stuck after a number of attempts( i've tried to evaluate the generating function of $A_{n}$)

Any hints that may help?

Comment: What did you get when evaluating the generating function? Can you tell us what you've got so far?

Comment: I got that $G(z)=\frac{1}{(1-z-z^{2})^{2}}$.
The next thing i would like to do is  to evaluate the $G(z)$ as a formal series in order to evaluate the terms of a sequence.

Comment: Have you tried to use partial fraction decomposition in order to get simpler terms?

Comment: It is going to like this:
$\frac{4}{5 \sqrt{5}(2z+\sqrt{5}+1})+\frac{4}{5(2z+\sqrt{5}+1)^{2}}+\frac{4}{5 \sqrt{5}(-2z+ \sqrt{5} -1)}+\frac{4}{5(-2z+\sqrt{5}-1)^{2}}$

Comment: Well now you can use geometric series on each term (the second and the last term is a bit tricky as it is squared) in order to get the coefficients for $x^n$ and then add them all up. You can pretty much follow the receipe used on page 9 in [generatingfunctionology](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~wilf/gfologyLinked2.pdf)

Comment: @flawr Well, as i understand, i'll get an explicit form after expanding these fractions using $\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^{2}+\ldots$, $\frac{1}{1+x}=1-x+x^{2}-x^{3}+\ldots$ e.t.c. (working with squares might be a bit complicated). Evaluating the coefficient for $x^{n}$ will be more than enough to establish the general term.

Answer (score 1):

Let $F(x)$ be the generating function of the Fibonacci sequence, and $A(x)$ be the generating function of your sequence.

We have $$F(x)= \frac{x}{1-x-x^2},$$ so $(1-x-x^2)A(x) = x + F(x)$.
By multiplying both sides by $F(x) $, we get $$A(x) = F(x) + F(x)^2.$$

Now, all you have to do is to compare the coefficient of $x^n$ on both sides.

Comment: For the detailed solution, see Donald Knuth AoP 1.2.8 or Concrete Mathematics by Knuth Potashnick Graham.