# How can I express Second-order Fibonacci number with usual Fibonacci numbers?

Tags: generating-functions, fibonacci-numbers

Second-order Fibonacci numbers are defined as follows:

$$
S_0 = 0;
S_1 = 1;
S_n = S_{n-1} + S_{n-2} + F_n
$$

How can I express $S_n$ in terms of the usual Fibonacci numbers $F_n$ and $F_{n+1}$?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1141276

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! ... The community prefers/expects a question to include something of what the asker knows about the problem. (*What have you tried? Where did you get stuck?* etc) This helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already understand or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you. An isolated problem statement with no evidence of personal effort makes a poor impression, attracting down- and close-votes.)

Comment: See also https://oeis.org/A001629